# How to run centerline command-line tool in windows 10 command promt

Tags: python, gis, gdal

I am attempting to run centerline from [here](https://centerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and can't figure out how to execute it.

I have python 3.7 installed here: `C:\Python37`

I have downloaded the package dependencies: `Fiona`, `scipy`, `GDAL`, `numpy`

I change directory to where the centerline folder is within my site-package and run the command as outlined in the documentation (link above) only to get a message saying it can not recognize `create_centerlines` as a command.

[image]

Comment: If `create_centerlines` is a `python` file then prefix `python` infront of the command like `python create_centerlines.py`

Comment: @faruk13, the strange thing is that there is no create_centerlines.py script:   [centerline package GitHub](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline/tree/master/centerline)

Answer (score 0):

From the github repo you referred, the `create_centerlines` file can be found inside the `scripts` folder from [this](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline/commit/293cb5f4ba4c91275ef92bf7094a8ecdf1fb92d4) github change.

So changing directory to the `scripts` folder and running `create_centerlines` should resolve your issue.

```
cd C:/Users/..../centerline/scripts/

create_centerlines <file>
```

Comment: When I `pip install centerline` there is no nested script folder as outlined in the github page. I am now attempting to run the tool in my python shell. The `create_centerlines` function is found within the `io.py` script. Instead of `from centerline.main import Centerline` as outlined in the package documentation, I run `from centerline.io import create_centerlines`, change my working directory to where my polygon shapefile's sit, then run `create_centerlines("PipePoly16.shp","PipeLine16.shp")` ... This has been running for hours so I think I am still missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround that gave me the output I need. As mentioned, `create_centerlines.py` is not included when I `pip install centerline`

I ended up just copying the `create_centerlines.py` code from [github](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline/blob/master/scripts/create_centerlines) and saving it in my `C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\centerline` folder.

In windows cmd promt I call the script:

`cd C:/Python37/Lib/site-packages/centerline`

`create_centerlines C:/path-to-polygon-shp/PipePoly.shp 
 C:/path-to-put-output-shp/PipeLine.shp`

After some long processing, the script ran succesfuly and I was able to view the PipeLine.shp in QGIS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a virtual environment and install the `centerline` package, you should be able to run the `create_centerlines` script from the working directory, as long as the virtual environment is activated.

I haven't used Windows in quite some time, but from memory, I had to add the path to the Python executable to the `PATH` environment variable, or [according to the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable), to the `PATHEXT` variable. There is also [a closed issue](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline/issues/10) with a similar question.